# Change email address

Tags: upgrade

We are transitioning from an older version (4.1.5) of CiviCRM to a newer version (5.8.2), and the email address is old (2 staff people previous to me) - how do I update it?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible they mean the info in the Organisation Address and Contact Info settings (Under Administration > Communication Settings)

or the CiviMail "From Email Address" (under Administration > CiviMail)